# What does this sentence and "make it" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I do not understand the part after *that*:

> Such was the nature of their relationship that **they never would have made it even if they’d wanted to**.

They would have never made it (made what?) even if they had wanted to (to make what?).

I encountered this sentence [here](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/conjunctions/correlative-conjunctions.html) in a grammar article. Therefore, there is no more context for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

**Make it** has several possible meanings, but one stands out as the most likely in this context:

> 6.1 (make it) Become successful [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/make?q=make%20it#make__27)

It is impossible to say exactly what this means without more information about the group of people under discussion. Is it a couple? Is it a band? Or something else?

For a couple, this might mean becoming successful in their relationship: for a band, it might mean becoming successful in the music business- selling lots of albums, performing at major venues, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of *made it* is the same as in:

> He **made it** to the finish line.

referring to a conclusion. So your phrase is saying:

> Such was the nature of their relationship that they never would have **had a successful relationship** even if they’d wanted to.

See [*make it*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+it).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility supported by the sentence as a whole: such was the nature of their relationship that they never would have **had sex** even if they wanted to.

*(From the Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary:)
— make it
2
:  to have sexual intercourse*

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your answer. More context certainly would have made the question easier to answer!